# Tuxcut installed But not running

Tags: dpkg

I have installed "TuxCut" application in my ubuntu. It has been installed but not running.It shows icon but not running. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Just type

```
sudo tuxcut
```

in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install some dependency just type :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install arp-scan
   sudo apt-get install dsniff
   sudo apt-get install arptables
   ```

   Note : 1 line is 1 command OR you can install them all in 1 command by using command bellow

   ```
   sudo apt-get install arp-scan dsniff arptables
   ```
2. You can install your tuxcut now open your tuxcut directory (if you don’t have this yet just download it)
   to installing tuxcut use this command

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i TuxCut-3.2_all.deb
   ```

   OR if your active directory not same directory with your tuxcut directory use this one

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i [tuxcut_directory]/TuxCut-3.2_all.deb
   ```
3. Your `TuxCut` ready to use

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in your terminal:

```
sudo systemctl start tuxcutd
```

Then run:

```
sudo tuxcut
```